# A different approach to $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q)\cong(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\ast$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

As it is well-known we have $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q)\cong(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\ast$. An approach often taken by textbooks is to *first* establish the irreducibility and degree of the cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_n$, *then* using this fact in order to obtain the isomorphism. This usually goes along the lines of defining an embedding

$$
\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q)\to(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\ast,\,(\zeta_n\mapsto\zeta_n^c)\mapsto\overline c
$$

combined with $|\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q)|=\deg(\Phi_n)=\varphi(n)$.

This approach strikes me as... impractical? Below I present a different ansatz which I find much simpler but which for some reason textbooks seem to avoid entirely.

> Show that $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q)\cong(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\ast$.

*Proof.* Since $K=\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ is a simple extension, the action of any $\mathbb Q$-automorphism is completely determined by its action on $\zeta_n$. Let $\sigma$ be such a $\mathbb Q$-automorphism of $K$. As

$$
\operatorname{ord}(\sigma(\zeta_n))=\operatorname{ord}(\zeta_n)=n
$$

all conjugates have to be primitive $n$-th roots of unity.

We claim that $\zeta_n^c$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity iff $(c,n)=1$. Indeed, if $(c,n)=d>1$ then we find $k,k'$ such that $c=dk$ and $n=dk'$, hence

$$
(\zeta_n^c)^{k'}=(\zeta_n^n)^k=1
$$

with $k'<n$. Conversely, if $o=\operatorname{ord}(\zeta_n^c)\le n$ we have

$$
(\zeta_n^c)^o=\zeta_n^{co}=1
$$

implying that $n\mid co$. However, since $(c,n)=1$ we deduce that $n\mid o$ and therefore $o=n$ as desired.

This leaves us with at most $\varphi(n)$ possible $\mathbb Q$-automorphism, as they have to map $\zeta_n$ to $\zeta_n^c$ for $(c,n)=1$, and any such choice yields a different $\mathbb Q$-automorphism. Hence $|\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)|=\varphi(n)$. Now the natural embedding

$$
\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q)\to(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\ast,\,(\zeta_n\mapsto\zeta_n^c)\mapsto\overline c
$$

yields the result. $\square$

> I see two potential problems with this proof:
>
> - It requires some rudimentary knowledge on elemetary number theory. The arguments to establish that $\zeta_n^c$ for $(c,n)=1$ are the primitive $n$-th roots of unity are based on some non-algebraic knowledge. I see how this could discourage their usage when there are purely algebraic proofs avaiable (which even are applications of earlier presented material on rings/fields).
> - Taking powers and, especially, interchanging powers of complex numbers is a problematic thing. Frankly speaking, I am note completely sure if what I have done is correct or relies on a wrong principle (I know that $(a^b)^c\ne a^{bc}$ in general for $a,b,c\in\mathbb C$; not sure if this matters here)
>
> Does someone have some insight regarding this matter? Is my proof correct? or at least savable without too drastic changes?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Note:** Once it is established that $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q)\cong(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\ast$ we get the irreducibility of the cyclotomic polynomials for free by simple degree considerations.

Comment: In some sense, the elementary number theory argument you use is re-used in the proof of irreducibility of $\mathbf{\Phi}_n$, so I don't see a problem. For the second point, there is no problem in interchanging powers, since they are all integer powers. Just to make sure I understand, when you write $\text{ord}(\sigma(\zeta_n))=\text{ord}(\zeta_n)$, you are referring to the order of an element in the group of $n$-th unit roots $\mathbb U_n$, yes? This is a pretty nice method. I guess we present the method with the irreducibility of the cyclotomic polynomials to introduce more tools, maybe?

Comment: @Andrei.B More or less, yes. This is meant as the multiplicative order in $\mathbb C^\times$, which should coincide with the one in $\mathbb U_n$. A common irreducibility proof I know of (due to Gauß IIRC) goes through considering $\Phi_n(x^p)$ and an elaborate modulo argument. But it might be the case that I just don't see completely through this argument to see its relation to elementary number theory. Introducing more tools (as application of ring and field theory as I referred to it) seems a like valid point to me too.

Comment: There is no problem with interchanging powers, because the powers here are integers. You don't need any branches here. However, I don't see how did you conclude that for each $c$ there is a indeed an automorphism which sends $\zeta_n$ to $\zeta_n^c$. You showed that there are at most $\varphi(n)$ automorphisms. In order to know such an automorphism exists you need to know that $\zeta_n$ and $\zeta_n^c$ have the same minimal polynomial. And for that we need the irreducibility of the cyclotomic polynomial.

Comment: @Mark Letting $\zeta_n\mapsto\zeta_n^c$ extends to a well-defined $\mathbb Q$-automorphism. That's the idea. Showing this, however, requires a bit more number theory as far as I can tell (to show surjectivity, in particular).

Comment: @mrtaurho But how exactly do you extend it? Such an extension exists if and only if these two elements have the same minimal polynomial. Seems like you didn't prove that. The reason why it is true is the irreducibility of the cyclotomic polynomial, this is their common minimal polynomial.

Comment: @Mark We have a power basis $\{1,\zeta_n,\dots,\zeta_n^m\}$ for some $m$ (as it's a finite simple extension). Extending here just means $\zeta_p^k\mapsto\zeta_p^{ck}$ for $1<k\le m$. And this, indeed, yields isomorphism as we have an inverse: the map induced by $\zeta_n\mapsto\zeta_n^{c'}$ with $cc'\equiv1\mod n$.

Comment: @Mark In fact, I did not thought this point through and realized - thanks to your comment - that I overlooked a critical step. So thanks for that! But yeah, that's the basic idea.

Comment: I think that your argument works when you replace $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{F}_p$ for any large $p$, which is a problem: the Galois group of $\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{F}_p$ is hardly ever $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ (it is cyclic, for once).

Comment: @mrtaurho When I think of it, it doesn't seem so obvious that this map is indeed an isomorphism. We need to show that the image of $\{1,\zeta_n,...,\zeta_n^m\}$ is also a basis. (not every injective function defined on a basis extends to an isomorphism, it happens only when the image is also a basis). Maybe I'm missing something simple, but looks like it is not as trivial as I thought.

Comment: @Mark Considering $cc'\equiv1\mod n$ (which exists since $(c,n)=1$) we have $\zeta_n\mapsto\zeta_n^c\mapsto\zeta_n^{cc'}=\zeta_n$, which readily extends to the whole basis, and hence gives and isomorphism. Once we have established that the assigment $\zeta_n\mapsto\zeta_n^c$ extends to a field homomorphism (at least for $(c,n)=1$) this gives use that $|\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q)|\ge\varphi(n)$ as desired. Do you see a flaw in this argument, I am missing at the moment?

Comment: This argument cannot work for, say, $n=15$ (so that $(\mathbb{Z}/(n))^{\times}$ is non cyclic) when one replaces $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $p > 15$. Where does it break down?

Comment: @Mindlack Could you elaborate? I see that this might cause a problem, but does it really apply always (at the least you would have to be careful whether $p\mid n$, which will alter things as far as I can tell)?

Comment: @Mindlack (Sorry for reposting my answer comment; now this looks really weird :D) This is a really good point! At the moment, however, I do not see the crucial flaw yielding to this false result. I will have to think about this first.

Comment: @mrtaurho Thing is, the inverse is defined on $\{1, \zeta_n^c,...,\zeta_n^{cm}\}$, right? But if this set is not a basis then you can't extend this inverse to a homomorphism. You need to check this is also a basis.

Comment: @Mark I would choose the $\{1,\dots,\zeta_n^m\}$ basis an view both maps foremost as $\mathbb Q$-linear maps of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$. I think once it is established that we have an isomorphism, the basis statement (i.e. that $\{1,\dots,\zeta_n^{cm}\}$ is a basis) follows.

Comment: To pinpoint an actual flaw in the argument: it is not obvious that $\zeta_n^a \longmapsto \zeta_n^{ac}$ (where $c$ is fixed coprime to $n$) and $0 \leq a < m=[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}]$ is actually multiplicative. Indeed, the image $\zeta_n^m$ is (up to sign) the "lower" part of the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$, evaluated at $\zeta_n^c$. So this is $\zeta_n^{mc}$ iff $\zeta_n^c$ is a root of the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$. This amounts to checking the irreducibility of $\Phi_n$.

Comment: @Mindlack That's very, very interesting; thanks for pointing out! (Feel free to make this an answer BTW)

Comment: @mrtaurho My point is this: suppose $V$ is a vector space and $B$ is a basis. You might define an injective function $f:B\to V$ and extend it to a linear map. Then you can obviously define a function $f(B)\to B$ which is an inverse of $f$. But if $f(B)$ is not a basis then the linear transformation will not have an inverse, even if $f$ has one. In your case, it is not obvious that the image of $\{1,\zeta_n,...,\zeta_n^m\}$ is a basis. (it is a set which contains some other powers of $\zeta_n$)

Comment: @Mark This seems to align with the comments from *Mindlack*. I'll have to think about this further, but it might be the crucial, although to me extremely subtle, problem with the overall approach. Thanks for your comments anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with this proof as written. Say that $(m,n) = 1$, and that $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity. It is certainly also the case that $\zeta^m$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity. But why does that mean there is an automorphism sending $\zeta \rightarrow \zeta^m$? That is, the condition that $(m,n)=1$ is certainly necessary but not (obviously) sufficient. (So the problematic part is "and any such choice yields a ... $\mathbf{Q}$-automorphism".) To prove this you need to show that $\zeta^m$ is conjugate to $\zeta$ for $(m,n) = 1$, which is (more or less) equivalent to showing that $\Phi_n(X)$ is an *irreducible* polynomial.

In otherwords, your argument as written shows that there is an injection from the Galois group to $(\mathbf{Z}/n \mathbf{Z})^{\times}$. It actually shows that if $F$ is any field (let's say of characteristic prime to $n$) that there is an injection

$$\mathrm{Gal}(F(\zeta_n)/F) \rightarrow (\mathbf{Z}/n \mathbf{Z})^{\times}.$$

But that certainly won't be surjective for all $F$.